# How to show confirm alert when Android Back button is pressed?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want to implement an alert on Webview page, when back button is pressed on Android. What code shall I use?

I Wrote below code in view1.js, but on pressing back button on Android alert is not being shown, it simply goes to the home screen:

```
$.webview1.url=Alloy.Globals.baseurl;
if(Ti.Platform.osname=='android'){
    $.webview1.enableZoomControls=false;
}

$.webview1.addEventListener('androidback',function(e){
    // show alert
    alert("Do you want to exit?");
    dialog.show();
});
```

But its not working. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
$.index.addEventListener('androidback', function(e) {
       if ($.webview1.canGoBack())
           $.webview1.goBack();
       else
           alert('open alert');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//create window
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

//create webview
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    url : 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
});

//add webview
window.add(webview);

//add event listener
window.addEventListener('androidback', function(e) {
    alert('open alert');
});

window.open();
```

Documentation:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback

Comment: Thanks Jagu, but here the issue is the Webview is opening in a seperate window. However in my case I have it open with a header and footer contstant in my app whether for native screens or of webview and on the top of it, my app's first page is webview. Any suggestions to solve my problem?

Comment: And my xml file has <Alloy>
 <View id="view1" bubbleParent="true" exitOnClose="false">
  <WebView id="webview1" willHandleTouches="false">
  </WebView>
 </View>
</Alloy> for the javascript $.webview1.url=Alloy.Globals.baseurl;
if(Ti.Platform.osname=='android'){
    $.webview1.enableZoomControls=false;
}

Comment: Add event 'androidback' to window parent of this view.

Comment: I believe its "android:back" with an colon.

Comment: @jagu is correct, the problem is that Molly is using a view and not a window... you need to use a window I believe

Answer (score 0):

The `WebView` doesn't have an event for clicking on android's back button, but the `Window` does, and that's why it's not showing the alert dialog.

You also have another error in `dialog.show();`, I don't see your initialization for that dialog and you're also calling alert exactly before it.
`alert` doesn't need to call anything to be displayed, but the `AlertDialog` does and it's better for user to see a title rather than the word alert, so always use `AlertDialog` if it will deal with the user.

Try the following code:

index.xml file:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win" onAndroidback="showExitDialog">
        <WebView id="webView" url="http://www.google.com" />
    </Window>
    <AlertDialog id="dialog" onClick="dialogClicked" title="Exit"
        message="Sure to exit?" cancel="1">
        <ButtonNames>
            <ButtonName>Confirm</ButtonName>
            <ButtonName>Cancel</ButtonName>
        </ButtonNames>
    </AlertDialog>
</Alloy>
```

index.js file should look like this:

```
$.win.open();
function showExitDialog() {
    $.dialog.show();
}

function dialogClicked(e) {
    if(e.index == 0) { // If the user clicked confirm
        $.win.close(); // Close the window or do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

I recommend reading the documentation, everything is there, check [WebView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView), [Window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback) and [AlertDialog](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-event-click) docs.

Comment: When I use the code above that uses Window instead of View, then the page is crashing.

Comment: I've edited the code, I forgot to open the window and the url was not in the correct format.